SSIS package executed from SQL Server Agent doesn't export full data to Excel
I have a SSIS package which exports data to multiple tabs to Excel, This doesn't export full data to Excel when run from SQL Server agent on server. It is checked to run as 32 bit. I have other packages which exports data to Excel and they all work fine but less data. I have only issue with this package. The highest number of rows it exports data to the tab is 22k.
There are 6 tabs that needs to be populated.
Tried following on the server:

The proxy account that executes the job has full access to C:\users\default
There is enough space on C drive.
Tried logging the errors when the job gives unexpected termination, but no new info was noticed.
No errors noticed in Windows Application log

Please advise. Thanks!

You're going to need to provide a bit more information than.

Sorry, Could you please specify the additional information you need?

Think about it if you were trying to assist someone remotely... what details would you need?

does it work when you run it from visual studio or whatever. What's the logic for the export

Excel has always had iffy row count limits. Sounds like your package could be using an older version of the 32 bit driver. What driver name and version are you using? Have you tried using something more recent?

Consider the possibility that it isn't the process, but maybe the data. There might be a value on row 22222 (or nearby) that is tripping up the process. Identify the last row that loaded and then look at your source data at and immediately after that row. Try loading the data in reverse order, or in separate chunks of 10k rows. It's a shot in the dark, but is worth a look.

@siggemannen , Yes, it works from Visual Studio perfectly. Logic: Execute sql task to create a excel tab , Dataflowtask: Oledb source to select the tablename, data conversion to unicode and excel destination.

@AlwaysLearning , Admin had installed from this link on the server recently: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

Your admins might have installed that package, but which driver and version are you actually attempting to create a connection with in your SSIS package? What connection string are you using?

@Alwayslearning,         Connection String for  Excel: Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=tp\Rem.xlsx;Extended Properties="EXCEL 12.0 XML;HDR=YES";   Excel Version selected on Excel destination:  Excel 2007-2010

Please let me know if you need more information. I am still having issues.
